# T-test while controlling for second measure

Tags: t-test, lm

I want to compare the means of a measure collected under two conditions $A$ and $B$. I have one observation per condition per subject so testing the difference against 0 using Student's t-test is obviously the way to go.

Now suppose I collected another measure under the some conditions that might be correlated with my first measure. How would I correct for that second measure? To put it differently, I want to test the difference in the first measure between conditions, that is not also explained by the difference of the second measure between conditions.

I thought about calculating my t-test as a glm and just adding a covariate, but I can't quite figure out the right way to do it.

Cheers,

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it as a regression of some sort. $X_1$ is a indicator variable that it $0$ when the subject is in group $A$ and $1$ when the subject is in group $B$. $X_2$ is your covariate. Then you have:

$$ Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 +\epsilon$$

You would test $\beta_1$ for significance to determine if the group differences are enough to account for different values in $Y$ when you have considered your covariate. You can include additional covariates using this method, too.

Comment: Thanks. Since I have paired values, shouldn't I use something like $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1  + \beta_2X_2$ where $Y$ is the difference over conditions in measure 1, $X_1$ is $0$ and $X_2$ is the difference in my second measure?

Comment: If you're interested in accounting for the differences in that covariate, rather than the values in that covariate, then your method looks fine. As far as the regression is concerned, the covariate is the difference between two values.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing this an it works well. Just for clarification, would this be equivalent to a one-way ANCOVA with just two conditions?

Comment: @MarcPabst I think that's correct.